# Is there a generic way to force your BOT to break in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I am writing a task in Automation Anywhere and would like it to break if a certain variable is set to "false". Is there a generic or standard code that can be used to accomplish this regardless of what windows or applications are open at the time the code is executed?

Comment: What do you mean by break? To stop completely, to throw an exception, to show a message? You can use breakpoints only in development.

Answer (score 0):

Your question in search for a "generic way" is a bit generic. But I believe you're looking for the [Stop Task](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/commands/stop-task-command.html) command. I would suggest creating a check for whether that variable is set to false and then stop the task.